# Magnetometer readings in metal heavy environment

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, magnetometer, sensor-fusion

We have designed a sensor board that consist a magnetometer, an accelerometer and a barometer which we are planning to use this on a forklift to get heading information of the vehicle. I have used Madgwick's sensor fusion algorithm to combine magnetometer and accelerometer values in order to get heading of the vehicle in degrees. This system works almost perfectly when not placed on top of the vehicle. When it is placed on the vehicle, magnetometer readings become unstable and this leads algorithm to fail as expected.

If I use a shield to prevent magnetic field of the metal parts, this will also prevent natural magnetic field, so the algorithm once again will fail.

Is placing the device far away from the metal parts the only way to get stable readings from magnetometer?

Comment: Yes. For magnetometer, physically separate from magnetic items including devices which carry high currents and metals which can retain residual magnetism. If you do a 360 rotation, you can probably distinguish between field fixed to the vehicle and earth field and possibly subtract it out later.

Comment: Short answer: yes. For indoor systems, you can use gyros, vision systems/ bar scanners to read strategically placed barcodes at waypoints. There’s also UWB technology that will give indoor location.requires a number of beacons. Qorvo have some product. Always pays to have two methods of location to cross check. Other techniques are rfid tags at regular intervals.

Comment: Mont it on a plastic pipe, away from metal. Use the compass to find a suitable position. Make sure the sensor orientation is correct, according to Madgwick.